# WPF change button content in user control while run method

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a button user control.
I want to change button content while executing user click event.
I try This:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickProperty = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
       nameof(Click), RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ButtonProgress));



private async void btnButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    btnButton.Content= "Please Wait...";
    ExecuteClickEvent(); // Run User Click Event
    btnButton.Content= "Its Done!";
}

//User click Event
public event RoutedEventHandler Click
{
    add { AddHandler(ClickProperty, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(ClickProperty, value); }
}

private void ExecuteClickEvent()
{
    RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonProgress.ClickProperty);
    RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
}
```

but it doesn't work correctly. When I remove **btnButton.Content= "Its Done!";** the button content will set **"Please wait..."** ,but when I put **btnButton.Content= "Its Done!";** the button content is "its done!" in all time.

Comment: It probably executes too quickly for you to notice?

Comment: The problem is, that the button refresh is queued on the Dispatcher. So it is executed after your method is done. The better way is to offload the `ExecuteClickEvent` from the UI thread. Use something like a `Task.Run()`.

Comment: I use Task.Run, there is an error `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

Comment: You are not allowed to manipulate UI controls other than the UI thread. So you should offload the CPU bound work from the UI thread. If the ExecuteClickEvent needs UI control access, you cannot TaskRun it. What is it, that consumes time?

Comment: sorry I can't speak english very well. ExecuteClickEvent run a click event programmer define : `<userControl:ButtonProgress x:Name="btnLogin" Click="btnLogin_Click" />`. could you give me some code please?

Comment: Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If `ExecuteClickEvent()` is being executed on the dispatcher thread, you could call `Task.Delay` just before you call it to give the UI thread a chance to update the content of the button:

```
private async void btnButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    btnButton.Content = "Please Wait...";
    await Task.Delay(1);
    ExecuteClickEvent(); // Run User Click Event
    btnButton.Content = "Its Done!";
}
```